# Сделать инклуд файла с html текстом

Tags: php

Как сделать инклуд с таким текстом:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.ru/js.js"></script>
```

Делаю:

```
<?php include('http://site.ru/inc.php'); ?>
```

Не инклудится

Comment: @Rammsteinik, заголовки какие по этому адресу приходят в ответе?  

`http://site.ru/inc.php`

Comment: Вы домен смотрите? Это пример.

Comment: @Rammsteinik, я понимаю, что это пример. Меня интересует, доступен ли ваш сервер, когда вы к нему обращаетесь (нет ли 500-ой ошибки?). Пытаюсь вместе с вами выяснить причину проблемы.

Comment: Ответил на свой вопрос.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не был прописан в `php.ini`

```
allow_url_include On
```

Answer (score 0):

Include('inc.php');

Comment: А разница? Путь сократили, и всё

Comment: Разница в том, что нет обращения к внешнему ресурсу. Не работает, что ли?

Comment: Как понять нет обращения к внешнему ресурсу? Путь прямой вроде.

Comment: Прямой путь куда? Http://site.ru - это что?
Вот здесь подробно http://www.php.su/include

Comment: Это пример как бы, не свой же сайт писать.

Comment: @Rammsteinik минусовал бы и минусовал за такие претензии. В первом случае php обратится к интерфейсу с просьбой запросить ресурс по сети. Таким образом, будет вообще запрошен сервер (сетевой ресурс), который с радостью выполнит php-файл, если он вообще есть и если dns не перенаправит в другое веселое место. Во втором случае php спокойно пройдет по файловой системе и прочтет файл напрямую.

Comment: Ну, точнее, если вообще сетевое подключение исполняемых файлов разрешено, я бы запретил от вот таких вот утех подальше.

Comment: Http://site.ru - это обращение к внешнему ресурсу, php не знает, как называется ваш сайт. Для того, чтобы php умел обращаться к таким адресам, надо версию выше 4.3 и прописать в php.ini allow_url_fopen=1.